# Theorem/Definition/Lemma numbering in Lyx

Tags: beamer, numbering, lyx

I want to independently number different environments e.g. theorems, definitions in beamer presentation done in Lyx. I did the module selection explained here [Theorem/Definition/Lemma/etc independent numbering in Lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112046/theorem-definition-lemma-etc-independent-numbering-in-lyx/286147#286147) and also tried other suggestions [Theorem/Definition/Lemma problem --- Numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45817/theorem-definition-lemma-problem-numbering) but still get this error:

LaTeX Error: Command \example already defined.
Undefined control sequence.

Can anyone explain where I am wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without any document to work with this question is hard to answer, but `beamer` does already provide an `example` environment