# LyX module for adding theorems, lemma etc

Tags: lyx, newtheorem

[Math environments such as Definitions, Proofs and Lemmas in LyX builtin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298761/math-environments-such-as-definitions-proofs-and-lemmas-in-lyx-builtin)

What module was the answer referring to? How do I upload such a module to my LyX software?

Edit: Unable to click "OK":

[image: Unable to click "OK"]

Second edit: Unable to click on "OK" nor "Apply" despite this module having no prereqs in the description:

[image: Unable to click on "OK" nor "Apply" despite this module having no prereqs in the description]

Comment: Do the instruction here help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112050/12212

Comment: I just gave it a shot. However, I'm having issues with using it for whatever reason- I'm trying to add Theorems (Numbered by types within chapters), but for some reason after clicking on "save as document defaults" or "use class defaults, nothing seems to work.

Comment: "save as document defaults" and "use class defaults" are different features. After adding the module, it will be saved in the individual .lyx file. After you add the module, you should then be able to use the new environments.

Comment: I did give that a go too, but it didn't seem to work out... I did click on "Save as document defaults, then closed the settings menu. I then proceeded to check if I could access them in the dropdown where you select the format which you're typing in (standard, Title, Author, Chapter, Subsection, Subsubsection etc), but did not see anything new added to it

Comment: "Save as document defaults" is a different feature. After you add the module, make sure you click on the "OK" button.

Comment: Eh, when I tried to do so, I noticed the "OK" Button is greyed out?

Comment: After you add the module, it is still greyed out?

Comment: When I try to add the module, it is greyed out. I'll update my post with some screenshots

Comment: Some modules requires other modules to be loaded first. The description should indicate what is required.

Comment: I see. I tried adding those other modules, but that "OK" Button just won't allow me to click it...

Comment: The problem is that the *Add* button is greyed out. It's greyed out for the reason Udi mentioned. First click on "Theorems (AMS)", then click "Add", then click on "Theorems (Numbered by type...)". Then click "Add". Then click "OK".

Comment: I did, when I did so it moved over to the right hand side of the modules menu, but nothing changed.

Comment: After the modules moved to the right side, did you press Apply? If so, the theorems layouots should appear in the layouts combo-box at the top left of LyX's window

Comment: Ah, that one's greyed out too....

Comment: I tried deleting and reinstalling lyx, didn't work either